# Giving variable inside WhenEvent a value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, syntax, procedural-programming, event-detection

I am defining ParametricNDSolveValue  in one cell and then using this in another one to find the parameter value using bisection. For clarity, I have simplified my differential equation. In order to obtain the correct result I need to clear kernel every time I run the code or every new iteration of the bisection in the second cell will give different and wrong answer (the right one is approx zero).

It seems to me that the reason has something to do with the variable yNeg inside WhenEvent but I don't understand what. In my understanding - every time Do loop calls integ previous value of yNeg should be cleared and set to -1. If the first event occurs (y'[x] > 0),  yNeg should be set to zero. If the second event occurs (y[x] < 0) , yNeg should be set to one. However, this happens only first time I ran the code.

First cell:

```
xStart = 0;
xEnd = 40;
WorkingprecisionVar = 23;
accuracyVar = Automatic;
precisionGoalVar = Automatic;
actol = 20;
integ = ParametricNDSolveValue[Clear[yNeg]; 
  yNeg = -1; {y'[x] == -a (x), y[0] == y0, 
   WhenEvent[(y'[x] > 0) || (1 <= x <= 2 && y[x] > y0), {yNeg = 0, 
     "StopIntegration"}], 
   WhenEvent[y[x] < 0, {yNeg = 1, "StopIntegration"}]}, {y}, {x, 
   xStart, xEnd}, {a, y0}, WorkingPrecision -> WorkingprecisionVar, 
  AccuracyGoal -> accuracyVar, PrecisionGoal -> precisionGoalVar, 
  MaxSteps -> 10000]
```

Second cell:

```
Y0 = 1;
funcPar[a_] := Quiet@integ[a, Y0];
bl = SetPrecision[-3, 30];
bu = SetPrecision[2, 30];
Do[NI = 0; bmiddle = (bl + bu)/2; 
 WorkingprecisionVar = Max[Log10[2^i] + 5, 23]; 
 Quiet[funcPar[bmiddle]]; If[yNeg == 1, bu = bmiddle, bl = bmiddle]; 
 NI = i; Print[yNeg, bl, bu, bmiddle, NI], {i, 20}]
SetPrecision[{bl, bu}, 30];
vala = (%[[1]] + %[[2]])/2
```

Comment: xStart has neither a value nor it is specified as a parameter.

Comment: it was just a typo when copying the code (added now)

Comment: What does "Quiet[funcPar[bmiddle]];" do? Further, e.g. "funcPar[1]" is not  a function.Perhaps you mean:" funcPar[a_] := Quiet@integ[a, Y0][[1]];"

Comment: ok, you can put funcPar[bmiddle]][[1]] inside the Do loop but it won't change anything w regards to my problem. point is that when you call funcpar[bmiddle] inside the loop for some value of bmiddle, yNeg will obtain a specific value. If you don't restart the kernel and run a 2nd cell again you will obtain different value inside the loop every time you run the cell

Comment: It would help if you post a minimal example of your problem, not the full blow one.

Comment: this is the minimal example

Comment: You specify:" integ = ParametricNDSolveValue[(*Clear[yNeg];*)
  yNeg = -1;..." Because of "=" this is executed at once, not when you call "integ". Therefore, "yNeg" is only set once to -1. If you call "integ" a second time, "yNeg" is NOT reset. What you must do use ":=" (SetDelayed) instead of "=" (Set)

Comment: thanks, but it seems that this doesn't solve the problem - same thing happens as before. when I ran 2nd cell for the first time I get 0.00048... when I ran it again I get 0.750..., for a third time -0.500... etc. there is still some memory effect

Comment: oh, I get it - if I put := at integ not yNeg. it work now! thanks!